# Use shapefile with multiclass as a training data

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

How can I use a shapefile containing different land cover classes as my training data in GEE?

Here is the code I am using,however there is always an error with the classification:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd52aa51ffe23daa95a33c1dfe95a42b

```
var training = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: EG_LC,
  points: 100,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
});


var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified')
Map.addLayer(classified,{},'classification', true)


// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```